# Unable to access span inside an li element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple web app. In one part of it, I have:

```
<ul class="sortable list-group">
  <li id="firstTag" class="tags list-group-item">
    <span id="present-count" class="badge"></span>
  </li>
```

I have to access both the li element with id="firstTag" and the span element with id="present-count".

Anyhow, I am able to access only one, if I remove the id="firstTag", I am easily able to acess the span, anyhow, in presence of it, js gives the error: "cannot set property "innerHTML" of null" for the statement:

```
document.getElementById("present-count").innerHTML = something;
```

EDIT:

Both are being called in window.onload function with "firstTag" called before "present-count". See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/poddarrishabh/2xzX6/3/

This is what I want the output to look like:

[image]

where both the "Present" text and the number can be changed.(I am using bootstrap).

Comment: *When* do you execute that call to getElementById?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2xzX6/1/

Comment: @RGraham Both of them are called when window.onload and also when any edits are made.

Comment: @laaposto See this one in which both are used: http://jsfiddle.net/poddarrishabh/2xzX6/3/

Comment: Try posting a fiddle that demonstrates your problem, because as @laaposto has pointed out, what you posted, works just fine. So your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @coder You are replacing the innerHTML of the `li` in your fiddle. `present-count` no longer exists.

Comment: @RGraham So what should I do instead?

Comment: @coder: Yeah, there's your problem then. If you replace the `innerHTML` of the outer element then you've replaced the tag you were looking for! What are you actually trying to do? What do you actually want the output to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just trying to put some text before the `present-count` span, then just add another span and target that instead of the wrapping `li`:

```
<ul class="sortable list-group">
   <li id="firstTag" class="tags list-group-item">
       <span id="another-tag"></span>
       <span id="present-count" class="badge"></span>
   </li>

 document.getElementById("another-tag").innerHTML = "some text";
 document.getElementById("present-count").innerHTML = "some more text";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    $("#firstTag #present-count").html();
```

add jquery file to your page and try this

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to create a text node:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("first");
document.getElementById("firstTag").appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById("present-count").innerHTML = "something";
```

Or to put the text *before* the span:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("first");
var present = document.getElementById("present-count");
present.innerHTML = "something";
document.getElementById("firstTag").insertBefore(textNode, present);
```

Here is an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3tBE/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code snippet

```
document.getElementById("firstTag").innerHTML = document
                                                   .getElementById("firstTag")
                                                   .innerHTML 
                                              + "first";

document.getElementById("present-count").innerHTML ="something";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this

```
document.getElementById("firstTag").innerHTML ='<span id="present-count" class="badge">' 
                                              + '</span>' 
                                              + ' first';

document.getElementById("present-count").innerHTML = 'something';
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2xzX6/4/)

You were getting this error because with the first

`document.getElementById("firstTag").innerHTML = "first"`

you were replacing the `<span>`, and your DOM looked like

```
<ul class="sortable list-group">
    <li id="firstTag" class="tags list-group-item">
        first
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you couldnt find the element with id `present-count` because it wasnt there.